# Want to display own event/schedule on calendar without reflect in native calendar in IOS (iPhone & iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nscalendar, ekeventstore

Display own app events, without reflect native calendar in IOS.
I am using pod 'CalendarLib'.

Please see bellow screenshot so you will get the idea.

[image]

Comment: So write some code that stores your events in Core Data or similar

Comment: No need to store. just need to display in calendar without reflect in native calendar.

Comment: You have to store it somewhere, even if it just in memory (but presumably you want the data to persist between runs of your app). If you don't want the items to be in the native calendar, don't store the data in the native calendar.

Comment: how we can display own event on calendar without save in native calendar? Also want to avoid other calendar events? Just need to show own app event on calendar.

Comment: Because of NSCalender and Event Store must need to use make custom calendar.

Comment: See I have already implemented calendar in my app. Just I need to change data source of event instead of native model want to use own model or similar.

Comment: Does that library support adding non-Events to its view? If it does, then simply add the data that you want to display to a dataSource (an array or a dictionary), then display it from the delegate method that library provides

Comment: There is no magic answer. Either the component you have selected supports non-calendar sources or it doesn't. If it doesn't you either have to modify it, if it is open source, or choose a new component that meets your needs

Comment: By the way thanks to all for participate on technical debate for my question. Do you know any tired party calendar which are allow own data source to display on calendar with day, week and month view? if yes then pls let me know.

Comment: I have done it, Using MGCDayPlannerViewController and MGCMonthPlannerViewController and implement the data source protocol methods.

Comment: @BhaveshKumbhani can you share your code. I'm kinda stuck in the same scenario would be really helpfull.Thanks

Comment: @Dlucidone, Download files from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B591Ke3ldqrfUTZfYXo5WXhCOVU/view?usp=sharing, Download demo of "CalendarLib" from github and Replace given files DayViewController, MonthViewController, WeekViewController. I hope you will get help.

Comment: @BhaveshKumbhani it would be great help if you could upload little demo project with your custom objects so we can get more idea.

Comment: @BhaveshKumbhani Yes Exactly If you can share code using some sample  Json and rendering it in the calendar would help us understand how you have handled this. BTW thanks for sharing code.

Comment: @BhaveshKumbhani I'm facing same issue and also downloaded your provided class & replaced it on my code. but now its giving an error as on below lines,,

_dayViewController = [[DayViewController alloc]initWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
        _dayViewController.calendar = self.calendar;

Comment: if you provide the demo code with your modification it would be so much helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Guys, Hope all are doing well!, going busy schedule so did not get time to prepare demo for you.  Now it is available on git. Download from https://github.com/BhaveshKumbhani/Custom-Calendar. Hope it will help to all of you guys. - Thanks

Comment: @BhaveshKumbhani and I want  horizontal scrolling in month and year view.do you have any idea?
 any suggestions are welcome:)

Comment: Can I change date format to am and pm format